# Bean instantiation notification in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I know Spring framework and have worked in it and have used `ApplicationContext` to instantiate and load beans.

Lets say I write the following piece of code

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");
```

Now, after the above statement, how do i get to know if the beans, that are defined in `appContext.xml`, has been instantiated and loaded by Spring?

Note : I want to know it before accessing any bean

Comment: What do you mean? If they're in the file and there was no exception they will be given to you when you need them, depending on what their scope is.

Comment: Actually I want to know before accessing the bean.I have just instantiated the ApplicationContext and want to know if it has instantiated any bean

Comment: If i get your question correctly you will see this following line in the server console `pre-instantiate beans [here all the beans in the appContext.xml]` when you start the server.And If you get any exceptions you will see `Destroying the bean .....etc`

Comment: Not sure what you're after. Is it just because you're trouble shooting something or want to understand more (in which case enable finer logging), or is it because you want to handle the error in your code? (in which case you try to get the bean from the context).

Comment: @SrinivasR - What if i run it as a standalone application

Comment: check out section 5.6.1 in the Spring Framework Reference. It covers the lifecycle callbacks (including initialization).

Comment: @Anand..... As long as you have proper  `Log4j` set up in your resource class path it will be same everywhere. Whether it is a server based or Standalone

Comment: This is a standalone I just ran . You should see this in your console.`INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory:557 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@42b307f0: defining beans [yourbean,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context]`

Answer (score 1):

Try retrieving one:

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) context.getBean("MyBean");
```

Comment: I have edited the post. I want to know it before accessing any bean

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Reimeus, and @jbx's comment. If nothing is thrown you should be good to go. If you really want to be sure though, consider using a logger, or even some sort of AOP to trigger an event when a bean is created.

I think I know what you're getting at, and it's something that's hard for us to do as programmers. Dependency injection (What spring does by creating beans in an application context) takes away the step of explicitly creating beans (ie. "Thing something = new Thing()") and that can be frightening, especially in early development when not everything is working, and you're not sure why.

Your objects are instantiated. You've just got to trust that Spring is doing it's thing--it will let you know if it's not :D

(also check out the BeanFactoryPost processor http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html , it will allow you to see what's there if you really want)